# updating request args in jinja2

Tags: python, flask

How do I go about updating a request arg, since it's not a user-defined variable Jinja returns the following error on page load:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '.'
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
{% set request.args.get('page') = page_num%}
```

What is the correct way to doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `request.args` is immutable.